# How to properly define a class object in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning the tkinter GUI in Python3.  I am making a canvas which has an oval and a button.  I'd like to click the button and have the width of the oval increase.  The button and the oval appear fine.  When click the button, nothing happens and I receive the following error message.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amjones20\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/amjones20/PycharmProjects/gui/guiPractice1.py", line 13, in oval_change
    Canvas.itemconfigure(self, oval, width=3)
NameError: name 'oval' is not defined
```

To me, it looks like the `oval_change` function is not recognizing `self.oval` in the `__init__` function.  I am not sure how to properly define `oval` so that it is recognized when the `oval_change` function is called.  Code is below

```
from tkinter import *


class GUI(Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, width=600, height=600)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.oval = self.canvas.create_oval(100,500,500,100)

    def oval_change(self):
        Canvas.itemconfigure(self, oval, width=3)

    def button_appear(self):
        self.button1 = Button(root, text="button", command=self.oval_change)
        self.button1_window = self.canvas.create_window(200, 200, window=self.button1)

root = Tk()

hex = GUI(root)
hex.button_appear()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve explain it better.

Comment: You need to consistently use `self.oval` to refer to this instance attribute.

Comment: @AD WAN I edited the question to explain it better

Comment: @jasonharper If I use self.oval as a parameter in item.configure, I receive an error stating " 'GUI' object has no attriubute 'tk' "

Comment: You didn't properly call the superclass `__init__()` in your `__init__()` - instead, you created an entirely separate canvas.  Either approach (inheritance or composition) is workable, but you need to be consistent about it - if your class instance isn't a properly initialized Canvas, then you can't call Canvas methods such as `itemconfigure()` on it (you'd need to call `self.canvas.itemconfigure()` instead).

Comment: @jasonharper How to initialize canvas is something I've been struggling to find.  Would you know of a resource that shows how to properly intialize Canvas?

Comment: Try `Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=600, height=600)`, and get rid of all references to `self.canvas` - `self` itself is now the canvas.

Comment: @jasonharper  Got it!  Your help plus the answer below makes sense and I got it working.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, this isn't a tkinter problem. Tkinter classes are really no different than any other python class, and the initialization rules are pretty much the same.

Consider this code:

```
class GUI(Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, width=600, height=600)
        self.canvas.pack()
```

You are defining a class that inherits from `Canvas`. The first problem is that you are not properly calling the constructor of the superclass so it's not being fully constructed.

Next, you are creating *another* canvas inside this canvas.

Since your custom class is itself a `Canvas`, there is no need to create a second canvas. You simply need to properly initialize the class you're creating, and then use the instance itself to create the oval:

```
class GUI(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=600, height=600)
        self.oval = self.create_oval(100,500,500,100)
```

Next, the error message is saying `name 'oval' is not defined`. That is because you are creating `self.oval` but not `oval`. You need to use `self.oval`. Also, you can call the method on `self` rather than the class:

```
def oval_change(self):
    self.itemconfigure(self.oval, width=3)
```

Finally, the code that creates the canvas should be responsible for placing it in the window:

```
hex = GUI(root)
hex.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Here is the complete program:

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI(Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=600, height=600)
        self.oval = self.create_oval(100,500,500,100)

    def oval_change(self):
        self.itemconfigure(self.oval, width=3)

    def button_appear(self):
        self.button1 = Button(self, text="button", command=self.oval_change)
        self.button1_window = self.create_window(200, 200, window=self.button1)

root = Tk()

hex = GUI(root)
hex.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
hex.button_appear()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  It makes perfect sense now that you've explained it.  I appreciate the time!

I have two more question.  The class I created inherits from Canvas.  What exactly does that mean?  And are there other things I can inherit from other than Canvas?

Comment: @AndrewJones: inheriting from a class means you are making a new class that is exactly like the original class, but with additional features.  Python classes can inherit from any other python class.